# Create React Add-ins for Office 2019 and 365

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

**Hello Community**
I'm starting with React Ad-ins for Office 365. But don't know How could I create a React Add-in for all Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Outlook?

Please help if anyone have done it.

Thanks and Regards
Duy

Comment: Refer this documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify which Office applications your add-in will run in by using the [Hosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/hosts) element in the manifest. Put a separate child [Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/host) element for each Office application and set the `Name` attribute. For the Word `<Host>` set the `Name` to `Document`, for Excel to `Workbook`, for Outlook to `Mailbox`, and for PowerPoint to `Presentation`. For details see [Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1) and [Specify Office hosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements).